# elements overlapping with my navbar dropdown tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have an issue with elements overlapping with my navbar dropdown

```
 <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
        <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
          <span>{{auth()->user()->name}}</span>
          <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        </button>
        <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
         class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg md:w-48 dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
          <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{route('profile.index', auth()->user() )}}">My profile</a>
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{route('profile.bookmark') }}">Bookmarks</a>
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{ route('profile.show') }}" >Profile settings</a>
                <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark:bg-transparent dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:text-white dark:hover:text-white dark:text-gray-200 lg:mt-0 lg:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                    onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout').submit();">
                    Logout
                </a>
                <form id="logout" method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                    @csrf
                </form>
          </div>
```

I tried to remove the absolute but then too much space was added. I tried to add z-0 I've read that z index is supposed to fix this. I'm new to css

Comment: you wanna implement a dropdown menu? @Shanediesel

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into codepen, I saw your dropdown always was open and didn't work correctly? I solved this question but if that isn't your answer, please tell me to solve it

```
<div class="p-10">
  <div class="dropdown inline-block relative">
    <button class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
      <span class="mr-1">{{auth()->user()->name}}</span>
      <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/> </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1">
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">One</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li class=""><a class="rounded-b bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">Three is the magic number</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```